# Docker COPY behaving inconsistently

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to copy whitelisted folders from filesystem into target container.

Basically I'd like to perform "complex" operation `cp -r app vendor target`, where `target` is a Docker container.

I have simple Docker file:

```
FROM alpine

COPY app/* /www/
COPY vendor /www/
```

For reasons unknown the first command doesn't copy the `app` directory itself. It seems that Docker doesn't distinguish the difference between `app` and `app/` which is quite irritating.

For testing purposes I've created following structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── foo
│   └── second
│       └── barf
├── Dockerfile
└── vendor
    └── bar
```

`docker build -t test . && docker run -it test ash`:

Result? Directory structure is not kept and parent directories not copied.

```
/www/
├── bar
├── barf
└── foo
```

`docker info`:

```
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
```

Can anyone explain me why Docker's `COPY . /target` and `COPY app/* /target` behaves differently? What's the motivation? Why Docker doesn't used standard semantic of UNIX `cp` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue in Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15858) which won't get fixed any time soon.

There are several workaround how to specify multiple folder and copy folder itself and desired content. Note that you can't use asterisk (e.g. `app/*` which would cause flattening directory structure.

**Multiple `COPY` commands**

```
RUN mkdir -p app bin config db lib public
COPY app/ app
COPY bin/ bin
COPY config/ config
COPY db/ db
COPY lib/ lib
COPY public/ public
```

In some cases this produce quite a long list and each command creates a separate layer in the image tree.

**Using `tar`**

Using `tar` and `Makefile` has an advantage that it behaves like a proper UNIX program (you can define exclude patterns, slashes, `*` etc.).

`Makefile`:

```
all: 
  tar -cf files.tar app bin config db lib public
  docker build -t image-name .
  rm files.tar
```

then in `Dockerfile` you have to use `ADD` command in order to extract files into desired structure:

```
ADD files.tar /www
```

**Using `.dockerignore`**

In `Dockerfile` simply copy everything

```
COPY . /www
```

and in `.dockeringnore` list all patterns that should not be copied:

```
.git
test/
doc/
log/
tmp/
Dockerfile
Makefile
```

note that once you're ignoring parent folder, there's no way how to manually copy single file from a folder that's already ignored ([related Docker issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15771)):

```
COPY doc/README /www
```

just won't be executed.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, COPY instruction copy files and/or directories from "/app" and adds them to the container at path "/www/". If you want to have a "app" directory inside of "/www/" then your COPY instruction should looks like:

```
COPY /app /www/app/
```

You can read more about COPY instruction in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy). Here I paste explanation of this behaviour from [it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy):

> If  is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.
>   Note:**The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.**

Regarding to your update: 
`COPY . /target` and `COPY app /target` behaves the same. It takes entire contents **from** source directory ( from `app` or from `.` directory ) and copy it to the `/target` directory.

You can see slightly different behaviour when you use wildcards, eg. `COPY app/* /www/`. It copy all files from `app/` to `/www/` but then it treat every single directory from `app/` like a source and copy its contents to `/www/`.

Why in Docker `COPY` is not implemented in the same way like it is in UNIX's `cp` command? I don't know, but if you want you can create pull request with own implementation :)

Comment: Can you list all directories on your local machine from "./app" directory? I'm pretty sure that you have "vendor" directory inside of "./app"

Comment: That's what I originally thought. Nope, it's not there. It is possible that docker behaves differently in case when target `/app/vendor` already exists in container?

Comment: I don't think so. I just tested it, I created Dockerfile and very similar structure  and it behaves exactly as I thought. Directory `/www/vendor` wasn't created, even when I created it before COPY instruction it was empty. Maybe do you have other process/instruction which create `vendor` directory?

Comment: Yeah, you're right it was created by another command. I've updated the question with full example, so that it's easier to reproduce.

Comment: I updated my answer regarding to your updated question :)

Comment: When the directory structure is not kept, I wouldn't call it the same. You can notice that the folder `second` is completely ignored. You might call it a feature but that's a bug for me.

Comment: If you want to keep directory structure then you should use command `COPY /app /www/`. When you use wildcards then each matching pattern is  resolved to your source and then if it is a directory then its entire content is copied to target directory. Keep in mind note from documentation: **The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.**. But in general I agree with you that can be confusing for new users.